# Having problems with a scoring loop by reading from a text file

Tags: loops, python-3.x, notepad, scoring

I am new to python and creating a quiz program. I have the questions and answers to the quiz on separate text files.

The text file for answers are all in lower case so I don't believe that the .lower() is the problem.

Here is my following code:

```
#Programming exercise-Writing to files

question_file = open("Quiz.txt","r")
answer_file = open("QuizAnswers.txt","r")


print("Welcome to the ScienceQuiz!")

question = question_file.readlines()

answer = answer_file.readlines()

score = 0

i = 0

for i in range(20):
    print(question[i])
    user_input = input("Enter your answer: ")
    user_input = user_input.lower()
    if user_input == answer[i]:
        score = score + 1
    else:
        score = score

print("\nYou scored: ",score,"/20")
```

At the end of the game even though all answers that I inputted were right it prints that I got 0/20?

Comment: Have you tried `print(answer[i])` to see if you are actually grabbing the answer you think you are?

Comment: @Shadow9043 yes I have and it does print the correct answer. Just doesn't add up at the end to print a correct score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is quite a common issue when reading lines from text files.
When you read a line from a text file, provided it is formatted like this:

```
    line one
    line two
    line three
    [empty line]
```

Each element of the list will be formatted like `line one\n` or `line two\n` as `\n` is the carriage return character for many systems. When you type the answer in your python program you would type just `line one` so when Python tries to literally compare the two, for obvious reasons it returns that they were different.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Add

   ```
   for i in range(len(answer)):
       answer[i] = answer[i][:-1]
   ```

   immediately after your:

   ```
   answer = answer_file.readlines()
   ```

   and it will remove the last character `\n` from each element. This would be the more commonly used solution.
2. Add `\n` to the user input:

   ```
   user_input = input("Enter your answer: ") + "\n"
   ```

Both solutions require that the last line of your `QuizAnswers.txt` be an empty line and nothing more.
Your `QuizQuestions.txt` will also have `\n` on the end of every line, meaning that printing them out will cause a seemingly inexplicable line break to also be output. You must use the `[:-1]` solution by looping through the questions to fix this.

Hope this helped,

Apples